# What does catalog:images:resize do in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, products, product-images

I am having a problem with how my images are displaying on my Magento 2 store.

And also I would like to know:

**What does `catalog:images:resize` in Magento 2.x version** ?

Comment: Are you asking of php bin/magento  catalog:images:resize

Comment: Yes i am asking in regards to **php bin/magento catalog:images:resize**

Answer (score 12):

> Generally, product images are cached while saving the product from
>   admin panel. However, sometimes you may need to re-create the product
>   images cache after you import products, if images were resized
>   manually in the cache, or if the cache was manually cleared by
>   mistake.
>
> **Command usage:**
>
> ```
> php <magento install dir>/bin/magento catalog:images:resize
> ```
>
> This command takes no arguments or options.
>
> The message **Product images resized successfully.** displays to
>   confirm the command succeeded.

**Source:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#resize-catalog-images

Comment: is there any way to catalog images resize for particular theme?
Suppose i have 4 themes and i want to resize images only for one theme then how can i achieve this?

Comment: With this command, there is no such way. Although you can customize the logic by overriding **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Console/Command/ImagesResizeCommand.php/** file.

Answer (score 6):

The images size is defined in `view.xml` of `<theme_dir>/etc/view.xml`. You can also manually modify according to your requirement.
For eg:

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="unique_image_id" type="image">
        <width>100</width> <!-- Image width in px --> 
        <height>100</height> <!-- Image height in px -->
    </image>
</images>
```

But, if you have following conditions:

```
 1. If you imported products which might have variable sized images
 2. If images were resized or deleted manually from cache
```

The magento `catalog:images:resize` command enables you to resize images for display on your storefront.

I hope this helps you !!

Comment: is it a good idea to modify this file?

Comment: YES. You can.
Copy `view.xml` of parent theme and paste to your theme with same folder directory.
Now you can change `view.xml` of your theme as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

`php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

It creates resized product images.