# Images are not displaying after installation of sample data In magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, sample-data

I have downloaded and installed latest version of magento(2.3.0) with sample data , everything went smooth but i am getting images are broken links, tried with both installing through sample-data repository and download by sample data zip file. but same issue i am facing.

Note: while installing through composer update getting issue with downloadable-sample-data as it is not available in http://packagist.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed issue with by running `"bin/magento catalog:images:resize"`. based on inputs from given link.
[What does catalog:images:resize do in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130725/what-does-catalogimagesresize-do-in-magento-2/130767)
few other errors i faced while installing magento 2.3
Js/css files appending versions : fixed by running

```
    step :1 
        INSERT INTO `core_config_data`
            (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0',
            'dev/static/sign', '0'); 
 step:2
        bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime images don't populate if cached version is not properly created.

**Below way worked for me**

- rm -rf pub/media/catalog/product/cache/*
- bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Answer (score 0):

> Note: while installing through composer update getting issue with
>   downloadable-sample-data as it is not available

**Solution**

- Do not install sample data if your Magento application is set for
  **production** mode. Switch to **developer** mode first. Installing sample
  data in production mode fails.

---

```
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

**[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html)**

> After installing, images and stylesheets do not load; only text
>   displays, no graphics

**[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html)**

**Details**

The path to images and stylesheets is not correct, either because of an incorrect base URL or because server rewrites (CentOS, Ubuntu) are not set up properly. To confirm this is the case, **use a web browser inspector to check the paths to static assets and verify those assets are located on the Magento file system.**

Magento static assets are located under <`your Magento install dir>/pub/static/`, within the `frontend` and `adminhtml` directories).

**Solution**

- If you are using the Apache web server, verify your **[server rewrites](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite)**
  setting and your Magento server’s base URL and try again. If you set
  up the Apache AllowOverride directive incorrectly, the static files
  are not served from the correct location.
- If you are using the nginx web server, be sure to configure a **[virtual
  host file](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html#configure-nginx-ubuntu)**. The nginx virtual host file must meet the following
  criteria:
- If the Magento application is in **[production mode](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html#production-mode)**, try deploying
  static view files using the command

---

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: if i am doing php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento sampledata:deploy getting error like minimum version number not available for magento-downloadable-sample-data.

Comment: Yepp you need to update composor for that

Comment: yes, i ran composer update, and also i added all sample data modules in require dev , again i ran composer update but no use.

Comment: Check composer version using composer -v

Comment: Or self upgrade the composer => composer self-update