# Magento 2.4.5 - Product images are not showing up on the front end

Tags: product-images, magento2.4.5

**Magento version - Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.5-p1**

Issue - Product images are not showing up on the front end.

I'm debugging this file, getting below data.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml


echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainImage);
exit;

Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [value_id] => 195402
            [file] => /c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
            [media_type] => image
            [row_id] => 56037
            [label] => CPFRG16/25-AT - Controlflex Coupling Frog
            [position] => 1
            [disabled] => 0
            [label_default] => CPFRG16/25-AT - Controlflex Coupling Frog
            [position_default] => 1
            [disabled_default] => 0
            [video_provider] => 
            [video_url] => 
            [video_title] => 
            [video_description] => 
            [video_metadata] => 
            [video_provider_default] => 
            [video_url_default] => 
            [video_title_default] => 
            [video_description_default] => 
            [video_metadata_default] => 
            [url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
            [id] => 195402
            [path] => /var/www/html/projectsetup/pub/media/catalog/product/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
            [small_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/75d5f1f9c56243b29d3c2276c04865ad/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
            [medium_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/426e0568c4ced36d62c614ab0f9619f2/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
            [large_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/982cff22d03368d7a9f3983da767218f/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
        )

)
```

I have checked this URL: http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg , I was able to open the product image.

cache images are not generating.

```
[small_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/75d5f1f9c56243b29d3c2276c04865ad/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
[medium_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/426e0568c4ced36d62c614ab0f9619f2/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
[large_image_url] => http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/982cff22d03368d7a9f3983da767218f/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg
```

Anyone faced the same issue? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try by running resize command Manually

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Source: [Mohit Kumar Arora Answer On Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/130733/78648)

Comment: Ensure you have writable permissions on this media/ folder. Change permissions to 777 recursively. OR This can happen if you change your Magento store from one server to another, you might have to change ownership of /media/ folder.

Comment: @Waqar Ali
I did try above resize command, not worked for me.

Comment: @Oscprofessionals I have checked and confirm that media folder has right permission.

Comment: @SureshChikani look for this image is the cache generated or not? http://local.projectsetup.com/media/catalog/product/cache/75d5f1f9c56243b29d3c2276c04865ad/c/o/controlflex-coupling-cpfrg16-25-at.jpg

Comment: Generated in the cache, generated path is different and product data images path different. @Waqar Ali

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010191/magento-2-products-missing-from-category-pages-after-magento-2-4-5-update/74010192#74010192

This linked helped me with images not showing on category page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the extension AbsoluteCommerce cache buster, make sure the override was not removing the code in the *pub/media/.htaccess* which you need to add according to the [cache buster documentation](https://github.com/AbsoluteCommerce/Magento2-CacheBust).

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am facing same issue no images are loading in front-end
My magento version is 2.4.5

Can anyone help me out from this ??*emphasized text*